# TestCafe gets stuck when using await async in expect assertion

Tags: javascript, testing, e2e-testing, assertion, testcafe

I'm using TestCafe and have the following code in the test which doesn't work:

```
test('Verify contents of allocation', async (t) => {
  await t
    .click(accountManager.selectAccount(inputData.testAccount))
    .click(homePage.icon)
    .expect(7)
    .eql(await dash.getPersonCount(inputData.totalAllocation));
});
```

The problem with the above code is that TestCafe says "Waiting for the element to appear" even before it hits the first line of the test and then gets stuck forever. I have no idea why this happens.

When I make the following change to the above test, then it works:

```
test('Verify contents of allocation', async (t) => {
  await t
    .click(accountManager.selectAccount(inputData.testAccount))
    .click(homePage.icon);
  const test = await dash.getPersonCount(inputData.totalAllocation);
  await t
    .expect(7)
    .eql(test);
});
```

Is there an easy way to prevent TestCafe from getting stuck?

And idea why it gets stuck in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to put enumerated values in the actual field. When you use the [Selector's DOM node state property](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/using-selectors.html#define-assertion-actual-value) or [client function](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/) promise as an actual value in an assertion, TestCafe activates the smart assertion query mechanism. This mechanism makes your test stable - see more about it in the [TestCafe documentation](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/assertions/#smart-assertion-query-mechanism). 
So please rewrite your test the following way:

```js
test('Verify contents of allocation', async (t) => {
  await t
    .click(accountManager.selectAccount(inputData.testAccount))
    .click(homePage.icon)
    .expect(dash.getPersonCount(inputData.totalAllocation)).eql(7);
});
```

The problem in your first example with the `await` keyword in the `expect` method relates to the execution of `dash.getPersonCount(inputData.totalAllocation)` before the test because this `await` breaks the test's chain.

Comment: I think here you mean `eql(7)` instead `expect(7)`. But when I run it without `await` then it complains - `Attempted to run assertions on a Promise object. Did you forget to await it? If not, pass "{ allowUnawaitedPromise: true }" to the assertion options.`. Even if I do that then I get this error `AssertionError: expected {} to deeply equal 7`

Comment: seems like whatever is being returned from `dash.getPersonCount(inputData.totalallocation` is curly braces.  Can you share the code of both the `dash.getPsersonCount` and `inputData.totalAllocation`?  That might help identify what is being returned....

Comment: `async getPersonCount(breakdownName) {
    return helper.getIntFromString(await this.getPersonCountLocator(breakdownName).textContent);
  }` // this basically return `int`
`inputData.totalallocation = 'total'`